# Categorizing each matrix element with some overlap between categories - using R

Tags: r, matrix, factory

I'm creating a function to categorize each element of a population matrix (PPM). For it, I created the function below. It works well for some matrix but doesn't for others, and I don't understand why!

My goal is to obtain an array like this

```
    [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]    
[1,] "Fert"   "Fert"   "Fert"   "Fert"   "Fert"  
[2,] "Growth" "Stasis" "Retrog" "Retrog" "Retrog"
[3,] "Growth" "Growth" "Stasis" "Retrog" "Retrog"
[4,] "Growth" "Growth" "Growth" "Stasis" "Retrog"
[5,] "Growth" "Growth" "Growth" "Growth" "Stasis"
```

#### The function

```
Categ<-function(x){
#x is your mean or sample population projection matrix
# Stasis
x[diag(x)] <- "Stasis"
# Retrogressions
x[upper.tri(x)] <- "Retrog"
xus
# Growth
x[lower.tri(x)]<-"Growth"
# Fertility 
x[1,]<-"Fert"
return(as.matrix(x))
}
```

#### Works well if

```
xus<-matrix(1:25,5)
Categ(xus)
```

#### However don't work if the array has "title"

```
hudsonia<-structure(c(0.4995, 0.00035, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.477275, 0, 0, 
0, 4.5782, 0.00335, 0.599, 0.19005, 0, 0, 12.1425, 0.0088, 0.199475, 
0.4679, 0.271475, 0.016175, 22.3167, 0.0162, 0.068725, 0.1246, 
0.545425, 0.2567, 50.1895, 0.036425, 0, 0.069225, 0.17115, 0.759475
), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(c("seed", "seedlings", 
"tiny", "small", "medium", "large"), c("seed", "seedlings", "tiny", 
"small", "medium", "large")))
```

Usage

```
Categ(hudsonia)
```

Comment: It's `diag(x) <- "Stasis"`; also, remove `xus` from your function

Comment: Try changing Stasis line of function  `x[diag(x) == x] <- "Stasis"`

Comment: Finally, what you think to maintenance this question here? It can be helpful for someone or is better to delete?